# Angular UI nested View with different parameter

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

angular: "1.3.15"
angular-ui-router: "~0.2.13"

TL;DR: **How should I provide a value to a nested view?**

[image]

For brevity's sake I'm going to greatly simplify the application in an attempt to focus on the problem. I have two main views called Customer and Refunds. Each main view has a shared nested view called Notes. The Notes view loads and displays notes relative to the customer at hand using a customerId. The Customer view's route has a customerId, but the Refunds does not. When viewing the Refunds view the notes section is hidden by default. Once the user selects one of the Refunds in the list I want the Notes view to load notes for the customer selected. Since the Notes controller is using `$stateParams.customerId` it will be empty when loading on the Refunds view. The Refunds controller knows which customerId was selected, but I need some way to tell the nested Notes view which customerId to load.

So far I have come up with a few options, but I'm not sure I like any of them, but here they are.

1. When the user selects a customer on the refunds page I can navigate to /refunds/:customerId. Don't like that because the page reloads and I have to set the selected item after the page reloads from the stateParams.
2. After the user selects a customer, use `$provide` to provide a customerId which gets injected into the NotesController. Don't like that because it's tacky and requires me to do the same thing on the CustomerController.

**Caveat**: I'm using ControllerAs syntax so scopes don't inherit each other. This prevents me from setting a customerId on the main scope and referencing it in the nested scope.

Answer (score 0):

In your parent scope, store the `customerId` in the current scope (`$scope.customerId = $stateParams.customerId`), and on the child scope, get the customer ID from its parent by`$scope.$parent.customerId`

Comment: I knew this would come up :) I'm using ControllerAs so scopes don't inherit from parent scopes. I updated the OP to explain.